# turn 2x16 dataframe into 4 x 4 matrix in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to convert a file into an adjacency matrix.  I need to do this in a way that allows files of different sizes to fill this matrix.  My current working file is of size 4.  This is my testing file, what I need is way of doing this in an abstract way to do larger files.

This is my test file. The 1 — 4 are the column that the Boolean values belong.

```
1,0
1,0
1,1
1,1
2,0
2,0
2,0
2,1
3,1
3,0
3,0
3,1
4,1
4,1
4,1
4,0
```

I would like an end result of:

```
0  0  1  1
0  0  0  1
1  0  0  1
1  1  1  0
```

Here is the code I have that produces a dataframe similar to my input file.

```
# Importing needed libraries
import os.path
from math import sqrt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# changing filepath to a variable name
fileName = "./testAlgorithm.csv"

# opening file, doing file check, converting
# file to dataframe
if os.path.isfile(fileName):
    with open(fileName, "r") as csvfile:
        df = pd.read_csv(fileName, header=None)
else:
    print(f"file{fileName} does not exist")

# method used to count the number of lines
# in data file
def simpleCount(fileName):
    lines = 0
    for line in open(fileName):
        lines += 1
    return sqrt(lines)

# method call for line count.
lineNum = simpleCount(fileName)
print(df)

num = int(simpleCount(fileName))
```

Comment: the data shared is of length 15, not 16. You can reshape with `np.reshape`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]})
    
df.values.reshape(4,4)
```

If you want to make it back to a dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(4,4), columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

Comment: I changed a few things on your algorithm.   First I made a list from my 2-d df into a 1-d list, Secondly, I used the length function to determine and took it square root.  This made my adjacency matrix doable for all sizes.  That being said your work solved my problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
dummy = pd.DataFrame(columns= [['c1','c2','c3','c4']])
dummy['c1'] = np.array(df['c2'].loc[df['c1'] == 1])
dummy['c2'] = np.array(df['c2'].loc[df['c1'] == 2])
dummy['c3'] = np.array(df['c2'].loc[df['c1'] == 3])
dummy['c4'] = np.array(df['c2'].loc[df['c1'] == 4])
```

It will give you as :

```
  c1 c2 c3 c4
0  0  0  1  1
1  0  0  0  1
2  1  0  0  1
3  1  1  1  0
```